# Line breaks being removed on save (PhpStorm on Windows)

Tags: php, sublimetext2, phpstorm

I am using Sublime 2 on Windows and another one of our developers is using PhpStorm on Windows. However when he opens up a file which I have edited, when he saves it, all of the code gets put on to a single line.

I previously had my Sublime set to Windows line breaks however I have changed it to Unix now and he is using Unix line breaks as well.

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Where do you keep such files -- FTP? Any VCS in use? Can you attach an example of such file (normal one, not broken; does not necessarily to be a real code -- as long as issue can be reproduced on it).

Comment: Using FTP, no VCS, been using binary FTP transfer as well.

Comment: I remember seeing one ticket (or forum thread) where after uploading file (from PhpStorm) and then downloading it back line ending was automatically changed (don't remember exactly: either removed or duplicated). That's the only thing that comes into my mind .. and I'm currently unable to find that ticket.

Comment: But that ticket may not be related to your case. therefore: does such change occurs before editing a file or after?; and is it local (broken text is visible in IDE) or remote only (after uploading back to FTP)? Can you disable any 3rd party plugins (not-JetBrain's ones) -- will it make any difference? What PhpStorm version is in use? an you try recently released v7?

Comment: 2 more questions: what is the 'Line separator' option value in Settings/Code Style/General? Please also check the line separator value shown for current file before and after editing - does it change? (note: it's shown in the status bar, in the lower right corner)